# react image component is not working

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone i am new to reactjs,and developing one app and i am getting one problem while displaying image using component.

Hereis my App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
     <Image
            source={require('./AAA.jpg')}
            style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              To get started, edit index.ios.js
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
              Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
            </Text>
          </Image>
  );


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   width: undefined,
   height: undefined,
   backgroundColor:'transparent',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
    },
  });
 }
}

export default App;
```

and webpack.config.js is as follows

```
var config = {
entry: './main.js',

output: {
  path: __dirname +'D:\myapp',
  filename: 'index.js',
},

devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
},

module: {
  loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     },
     {
            test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|json)$/,
            loader: 'file',
            query: {
              name: '[name]--[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          }
  ]


  }
  }

module.exports = config;
```

IN this webpack i have added loader for jpg images also

But image is not displaying. i dont have the idea about what to do.

Please give me the suggection tosolve my problem this is my first app and i am getting problem

Comment: You are using component <Image /> that is not imported to your App.jsx.

Answer (score 0):

You need not define a specific loader to load an image using html image tag

just use

<`img src="image path" height="20px" witdh="20px"/>`

It will work fine and if you want responsive image then you can use react bootstrap image tags

Comment: image is larger so it is not fit to screen.i want to responcive code to fit image to screen

Comment: updated the answer.you can adjust height using height attribute

Comment: hope you have imported eveything required

Answer (score 0):

Dont add anything to webpack , and by seeing ur code u r missing imports 
use
 `import React, {Component} from 'react';`
`import  {Image, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'`
and declare stylesheet outside component .